# Is there a way to make a UITableViews sections handle touch events?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a simple way or methods for allowing touches to be handled in sections(headings) and to track which section(heading) was touched?

I only want to draw the cells for a section when the user presses that section. But i want all the sections to always be visible.

I know i can hack that by make the headings be represented as cells and then draw extra cells below that cell when its touched. But its kinda hacky i guess.

Thanks,
Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to provide a custom section header view for your table view that contains some control, like a button, that can handle those touches for you.

Take a look at [`UITableViewDelegate`'s `viewForHeaderInSection:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aviewForHeaderInSection%3a). You can use the section number that comes from that method to identify which section of cells to reveal as the user touches a button in that section header view.

Comment: As it's done in the [Table View Animations and Gestures](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewUpdates/Introduction/Intro.html) sample from apple. @Code you should look at this project, I think it's exactly what you want.